# Applying replication on the single partition of the table

Tags: mysql

i want to applying replication on the single partition of the table.
the table is partition by hash partition techices. My mysql master sever is production box in which ETL scripts working and data inserting table very frequently and partition on the base on the client id .
Please help me to applying replication on the single partition of the table.

Comment: Why do you want to replicate ***only a single partition*** from that specific table? Why not the **entire table**?

Comment: using replication i want to separate data for one client e.g---for client id 38 is very large data and my mysql server is production server in which ETL script run and loading large data frequently.Please help me to solve this problem.